# Infinite loop in implementation of Euclid's greatest common denominator method

Tags: java, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

Logical Error with the second `println` statement causes an infinite loop in my code below.

It's inside the while loop which I understand causes it to keep printing because the while test is true. Using 48 and 18 as num1 and num2 respectively, I get the correct answer of the GCD being 6. The placement of the print out statement is wrong, and I cannot figure out where to put it.

My code finds the GCD of two integers as long as either are not negative. I used Euclid's method.

Thanks for any help!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Chapter5Lab_Problem1 {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type the first integer to find GCD");
    int num1 = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Type the second integer to find GCD ");
    int num2 = console.nextInt();
    gcd(num1,num2);
  }

  public static void gcd( int x, int y){
    while( x >= 0 && y >= 0){
      if( x == 0){
        System.out.println("The GCD is " + y);
      }
      while( y != 0){
        if( x > y){
          x = x - y;
        }else{
          y = y - x;
        }

      }
     System.out.println("The GCF is " + x); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: why are you successively subtracting instead of getting the mod.

Comment: Wasn't sure how to use it correctly. Can you show me how you would alter the method using modulus instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X and Y will always be >= 0. The minimum they can become in this algorithm is 0, thus the condition for the first while statement always holds. Try `x > 0 && y > 0` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Sheesh it's always something so simple. I was driving myself crazy trying to find where to put the SOP statement. Completely overlooked that. Much appreciated, sir!

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive answer. Teachers love recursion. Recursion is risky when it is  infinite or too long of a stack for the program to hold.

```
public static int GCD(int n1, int n2){

  if(a==0 || b==0)
    return a+b;

  return GCD(n2, n1%n2)
}
```

If you must do a loop, here is that implementation

```
int n3;
while(n != 0 || n2!= 0){

  n3 = n2;
  n2 = n1%n2;
  n1 = n3;
}

return n1+n2;
```